# Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.[entries with non-ascii characters]

Tags: citing, natbib, ascii

I checked various related answers but, I am new to Natbib and couldn't figure out the problem if you might please be able to help. Here is the tex code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
% for 2-column layout use \documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}   %values: small,big | online,print,work
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
% New theorem-like environments will be introduced by using the commands \theoremstyle and \newtheorem.
% Please note that the environments proof and definition are already defined within dgryuter.sty.


\begin{document}

Power system oscillations’ behavior is a dominant thought in the power system stability discipline\cite{Pérez-Londoño:2012,Muñoz:2011}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Pérez-Londoño:2012}
\href{https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6319119}{S. Pérez-Londoño, L. Rodríguez-García, Y. U. López.  Effects of doubly fed wind generators on voltage stability of power systems. In \emph{2012 Sixth IEEE/PES Transmission and Distribution: Latin America Conference and Exposition (T{\&}D-LA)}; 2012; Montevideo, Uruguay: pp. 1-6. doi: 10.1109/TDC-LA.2012.6319119}

\bibitem{Muñoz:2011}
\href{https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5772545}{J. C. Muñoz, C. A. Cañizares. Comparative stability analysis of DFIG-based wind farms and conventional synchronous generators. In \emph{2011 IEEE/PES Power Systems Conference and Exposition, PSCE} 2011; Phoenix, AZ, USA: pp. 1-7. doi: 10.1109/PSCE.2011.5772545}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless you are using a Unicode engine (LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX) it is probably safer not to use non-ASCII characters in entry keys. While recent LaTeX releases support non-ASCII characters in some places even with pdfLaTeX, it is often safer to stick to ASCII. `\bibitem{Perez-Londono:2012}` and `\bibitem{Munoz:2011}` will work fine.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: For the avoidance of confusion a small addendum to my comment above: The advice to stick with ASCII applies to those parts of your source that are not simple text. For simple text (with a modern LaTeX kernel) pdfLaTeX actually supports a sizeable chunk of UTF-8 that works well for many languages in Latin script. The trouble usually only comes in when non-ASCII characters are needed for internal identifiers like labels or command names. (Even there LaTeX has some support in some areas, but it's slightly trickier to make sure everything works as can be seen here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it already -- you cannot use non-ascii characters like öäüñ etc. in citations. These characters are not in the ascii table and only found in other more extensive tables like UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Refactoring your use of "ñ" into simple "n" should fix your problem. It is probably not necessary to refactor the content of the citation but only the citation tag (i.e. `\bibitem{Muñoz:2011}` into `\bibitem{Munoz:2011}`).

Comment: the answer is accepted. TThanks a lot